# Docusign In-Person signing Session Time out

Tags: docusignapi

During In-Person signing a session timeout error is thrown from docusign between the first signer and second signer only - 
https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/SessionTimeout.aspx?...

if there are 3 signers then it behaves properly between 2nd and 3rd signer. But throws session timeout error after when the 1st signer completes the signing and before when the URL is redirected to the 2nd signer.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please **edit** your question to supply *a lot more* information. Are you using the API? What envelope creation request are you using (what is the JSON)? How are you initiating the first signer and how are you switching between signers? Are all of the signers "In-person" recipients? Why aren't you using "Signer Recipients?" Unless you supply useful information in your question, it will be closed.

Comment: I am Using Docusign API (that is the reason I have tagged docusignapi) and Why am I not using Signer Recipients ? - because that is not the requirement that the client is looking for. I will provide further information by editing the question.

Comment: Would it be possible to also share a high level breakdown of the API calls you are making sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewall or proxy
If you are connecting to the Internet behind a firewall or through a proxy the firewall or proxy may be restricting or prohibiting the session from being established.
•   Users accessing the Internet behind a Proxy Server must enable HTTP 1.1 settings via proxy connection
•   Firewall settings must allow access to the following servers :

http://*.docusign.net

https://docucdn-a.akamaihd.net

**ip ranges**

https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/ip-ranges/

•   Other site related issue - If this issue is only occurring on http://*.docusign.net and you're not encountering any of the above-related issues it's possible that it could be the site encountering an issue - In that case, please contact DocuSign Support.